# Polars vs. Pandas: size and speed difference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-polars

I have a `parquet` file (~1.5 GB) which I want to process with `polars`. The resulting dataframe has 250k rows and 10 columns. One column has large chunks of texts in it.

I have just started using polars, because I heard many good things about it. One of which is that it is significantly faster than pandas.

**Here is my issue / question:

The preprocessing of the dataframe is rather slow, so I started comparing to `pandas`. Am I doing something wrong or is polars for this particular use case just slower? If so: is there a way to speed this up?**

Here is my code in `polars`

```
import polars as pl

df = (pl.scan_parquet("folder/myfile.parquet")
      .filter((pl.col("type")=="Urteil") | (pl.col("type")=="Beschluss"))
      .collect()
     )
df.head()
```

The entire code takes roughly **1 minute** whereas just the filtering part takes around **13 seconds**.

My code in `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = (pd.read_parquet("folder/myfile.parquet")
    .query("type == 'Urteil' | type == 'Beschluss'") )
df.head()
```

The entire code also takes roughly **1 minute** whereas just the querying part takes **<1 second**.

The dataframe has the following types for the 10 columns:

- i64
- str
- struct[7]
- str (for all remaining)

As mentioned: a column "`content`" stores large texts (1 to 20 pages of text) which I need to preprocess and the store differently I guess.

> **EDIT**: removed the size part of the original post as the comparison was not like for like and does not appear to be related to my question.

Comment: Whenever the record size goes over a million I use Pyspark, in other cases always Pandas.

Comment: What does `df.memory_usage(deep=True)` say in pandas?

Comment: `df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()` results in `9710410625`. So I guess `.info()` was not the equivalent. But still, pandas is so much faster.

Comment: Did you include the time needed to load the data in memory? Polars is using lazy evaluation and loads data only when needed. Try using `scan_parquet(..).filter(..)` and compare the time needed with the full loading and processing time in pandas

Comment: The time incl. loading into memory is approximately the same for both (ca. 1 Minute). I use `pl.scan_parquet(...).filter(...).collect()` for polars.

Comment: Hi @FredMaster, what about if you set the column as categorical before running the filter? `df = df.with_columns(pl.col('type').cast(pl.Categorical)) `

Comment: Hi @Luca. I had a very similar thought a couple minutes ago. Unfortunately, it doesn't really have an impact on computation time. I was actually wondering if polars is not suited for columns with large chunks of text?

Comment: Can you show your code for polars and pandas? You might be comparing apples with oranges.

Comment: Hi @ritchie46. I have just updated the original post. Does this help?

Comment: Categorical will help if you initially save it that way.  Converting to categorical on the fly just moves the expense to that conversion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As mentioned: a column "content" stores large texts (1 to 20 pages of text) which I need to preprocess and the store differently I guess.

This is where polars must do much more work than pandas. Polars uses `arrow` memory format for string data. When you filter your `DataFrame` all the columns are recreated for where the `mask` evaluates to `true`.

That means that all the text bytes in the string columns need to be moved around. Whereas for pandas they can just move the pointers to the python objects around, e.g. a few bytes.

This only hurts if you have really large values as strings. E.g. when you are storing whole webpages for instance. You can speed this up by converting to categoricals.

Comment: Ok, understood. So I take this in mind when using polars. Overall, I am really impressed with the library. Great work!

Answer (score 0):

My first suspicion was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75168994/1818713) which was written by the author of Polars.

> Polars does extra work in filtering string data that is not worth it in this case. Polars uses arrow large-utf8 buffers for their string data. This makes filtering more expensive than filtering python strings/chars (e.g. pointers or u8 bytes).

Then I did the following...

```
import polars as pl
import time
import numpy as np
num_rows=20000000
df=pl.DataFrame({'a':np.random.choice(
    ['apple','banana','carrot','date','eggplant'], num_rows), 
                 'b':np.random.rand(num_rows),
                 'c':np.random.rand(num_rows),
                 'd':np.random.rand(num_rows)})


%%timeit
df.filter((pl.col('a')=='apple') | (pl.col('a')=='banana'))

# 453 ms ± 39.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)



import pandas as pd
dfpd=df.to_pandas()

%%timeit
dfpd.query("a=='apple' | a=='banana'")

# 2.25 s ± 64.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

My `pl.show_versions`:

```
---Version info---
Polars: 0.16.2
Index type: UInt32
Platform: Linux-5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2-x86_64-with-glibc2.35
Python: 3.10.9 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Feb  2 2023, 20:20:04) [GCC 11.3.0]
---Optional dependencies---
pyarrow: 11.0.0
pandas: 1.5.3
numpy: 1.23.5
fsspec: 2023.1.0
connectorx: 0.3.1
xlsx2csv: 0.8.1
deltalake: <not installed>
matplotlib: 3.6.3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My take away: polars is not generally slower than pandas when filtering a column that contains str. So maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @FredMaster if you run my test, does your polars go faster than pandas?

Comment: Yes, polars is about 3 to 4x faster. But of course I could optimize the pandas part, e.g. `dfpd[dfpd['a'].isin(['apple','banana'])]`  which reduces the speed advantage of polars.

Comment: polars also has isin, it's just that it's `is_in`